# Duplicate zip entry retrofit-1.3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, retrofit

I get an error when I try to create signed Apk with Proguard activated, relative to a duplicate zip entry with retrofit :

```
Note: there were 110 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-1.3.2.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-1.3.2.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
:app:proguardAppRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardAppRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/me/Projects/myProject/app/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/app/release/classes.jar] (Can't read [/Users/me/Projects/myProject/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/myProject/mySubProject/unspecified/jars/libs/retrofit-1.3.0.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [b/a/a.class == retrofit-1.3.0.jar:retrofit/android/AndroidApacheClient.class]))
```

Here my dependancies in my build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.11') {
        exclude group: 'commons-io', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.4')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.0.5'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/PushLinkAndroid-5.3.0.jar')
    compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.5.4')
}
```

And also I have added this packaginOptions :

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'README.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
```

I would like to know if it's possible maybe to fix this problem by excluding retrofit-1.3.0 from my compile('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.11') or if there is another better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add it to your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
     packagingOptions { 
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' 
     }
 }
```

**Edit**

According to [this issue](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/365) which is the same with your problem, you can do it like that.

```
compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.13') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: I've already added this in my build.gradle but it still doesn't work.

Comment: yes clean and rebuild. Still get the same error. I think I have to exclude this dusplicate zip entry but don't know exactly how.

Comment: I've just fixed my problem thanks to all the information that you have provided in your updated answer. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad to hear that ! :)

Comment: I don't know what's happened. But when I wrote you my last comment I got a message on android studio which told me signed apk created with success and from this moment then I tried to recreate my signed apk and I still get this error.... I'm going te recreate a new question for more clarity. Anyway your answered help to fix one problem.

Answer (score 0):

My dependencies section had both

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    } and compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']).
```

That means I had included the library twice hence the error. Everything worked as expected when removed `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` from dependencies